# Brand new to VBA. Need assistance with macro to add series to a chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA so I am struggling to make what I feel should be a simple macro. I have researched for a long time on here trying to figure it out, but I can't understand whats wrong. I have 200 series in rows 1 to 200 in excel. Each series has two x values (in B and C) and two y values in (D and E) and I am trying to make a XYScatterLine graph. I would like to make a macro that adds all 200 of these series onto the chart. I have attempted to write a macro below but it is not working and I am getting confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Sub graph()
    Dim a
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    For a = 1 To 200
        With ActiveChart
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .XValues = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("B" & a & ":C" & a)
                .Values = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("D" & a & ":E" & a)
                .Name = "name"
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I feel like my mistakes start at the .Xvalues line because the chart generates but no series are plotted. I really appreciate any help that you can provide!

Comment: Put the sheet names in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub graph()

Dim cht As Chart
Dim a, sht

    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    cht.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    For a = 1 To 19
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "name"
            .Values = sht.Range("D" & a & ":E" & a)
            .XValues = sht.Range("B" & a & ":C" & a)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=[Add Series Name]"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$200"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$D$1:$D$200"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=[Add Series Name]"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$200"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$E$1:$E$200"
```

You may need to amend the column references I have used, if they don't exactly match your worksheet.

I would also note that this code is pretty static and won't change should your dataset increase to more than 200 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sheet names in quotes. That is, change this:

```
            .XValues = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("B" & a & ":C" & a)
            .Values = Sheets(Sheet1).Range("D" & a & ":E" & a)
```

to this:

```
            .XValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & a & ":C" & a)
            .Values = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & a & ":E" & a)
```